# How can I push a new Book object into empty array using Class syntax?

Tags: javascript, class, refactoring

If a constructor in the class declaration already creates a book **object**, If i'm thinking about this correctly, all I would need to do is instantiate the object, then push that object into an array. What am I missing here?

```js
class Book{
  constructor(title, author, pages, hasRead, library=[]){
    this.title = title
    this.author = author
    this.pages = pages
    this.hasRead = hasRead
    this.library = library
  }

  
addBookToLibrary(){
   return this.library.push();
 }
}

//instantiate Book Object
let newBook = new Book();

//push the object into the empty array??
newBook.addBookToLibrary("A book", "Charlie Morton", "500", true);


console.log(newBook.library);
```

Comment: `addBookToLibrary` doesn't accept any arguments, nor are you passing anything to `.push`

Comment: And the code conflates two separate things: a `Book` is not a `Library`, a `Library` *has-many* `Book`.

Comment: @DaveNewton That makes sense. Would I separate the Library array outside of the class and just allow it to be a global variable then? Then push new books into this array?

Comment: There's many ways it could be implemented; that's one option. I might wrap up library-ish ops in a `Library` class, though, for a variety of reasons.

Comment: Modify what you are sending to the addBookToLibrary like: newBook.addBookToLibrary({ title: "A book", author: "Charlie Morton", pages: "500", hasRead: true })

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated, originally you were not passing any arguments to your push method. If you are looking to create an array of arrays like:

[
[
"A book",
"Charlie Morton",
"500",
true
],
[
"Two book",
"Charlie Morton",
"200",
false
]
]

Though I think an array of objects with key:value pairing would make it easier to use.

```js
class Book{
  constructor(title, author, pages, hasRead, library=[]){
    this.title = title
    this.author = author
    this.pages = pages
    this.hasRead = hasRead
    this.library = library
  }
  
  addBookToLibrary(book){
     return this.library.push(book);
  }
}

//instantiate Book Object
const newBook = new Book();


//push the object into the empty array??
newBook.addBookToLibrary(["A book", "Charlie Morton", "500", true]);
newBook.addBookToLibrary(["Two book", "Charlie Morton", "200", false]);


console.log(newBook.library);
```